# Why in react-native does the same scene gets render again using this.props.navigator.replace?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

I'm playing with react-native and the in the particular with the `navigator` component. I've got a simple login scene where after pressing a button I would like to be redirected to another page.

I couldn't understand why when I press the button I get the same scene rendered again. Instead of going to MainScreen I got routed to LoginScreen again.

**index.ios.js**

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Navigator,
    } = React;

var MainScreen = require('./MainScreen');
var LoginScreen = require('./LoginScreen');

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Navigator
                style={styles.navigationContainer}
                initialRoute={{id: 'LoginScreen', name:'Login'}}
                renderScene={(route, navigator) =><LoginScreen navigator={navigator}/>}
                />
        );
    }
});


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    navigationContainer: {
        flex: 1
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

**LoginScreen.js**

```
  'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var windowSize = Dimensions.get('window');

var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    Image,
    TouchableHighlight
    } = React;

var MainScreen = require("./MainScreen");

var LoginScreen = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        }
    },
    goToMainScreen: function () {
        this.props.navigator.replace({
            id: MainScreen
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Image style={styles.mark} source={{uri: ''}} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.usernameAndPasswordContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.input}
                            enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
                            onEndEditing={event => this.setState({username: event.nativeEvent.text})}
                            placeholder="Username"
                            placeholderTextColor="#002A32"
                            />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput
                            password={true}
                            style={styles.input}
                            placeholder="Password"
                            placeholderTextColor="#002A32"
                            onEndEditing={event => this.setState({password: event.nativeEvent.text})}
                            />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    style={styles.signin}
                    onPress={this.goToMainScreen.bind(this)}
                    >
                    <Text>Sign in!</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({ ... });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `renderScene` method needs to know which component to render but you are always sending it the LoginScreen component. Do something like this:

```
renderScene: (route, navigator) {
  Component = route.component
  <Component navigator={navigator} route={route} />
}
```

This means that you move to a new scene by passing a component key to the navigator.

```
this.props.navigator.replace({
  component: MainScreen
});
```